# Replace hardcoded sql select query used in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have the following code :

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("Select a,b from MyTableA inner join MyTableB on  MyTableA.column = MyTableB.column);
```

This is working well, it returns me a list of MyEntityType filled with MyTable and MyTableB.

The problem is that I have my select hardcoded in my csharp file. I would like to have it in a sql object and just put there the name of this sql object. But I don't know how to do it. Did I have to put it in a stored proecudre or a function? If yes, is just replacing my hardcoded query with the name of this function or stored procedure would be enough?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You wrote You are using entity-framework. EF have tutorials how to use it & how to handle objects with LINQ queries. Have u seen that? [link to tutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I typically use stored procs for custom queries like this, and yes, you simply access it using the name of the proc:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("my_stored_proc")
```

You can also do this with procs that take parameters:

```
var my_param = new SqlParameter("@param1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
my_param.Value = 123;

context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("my_stored_proc_with_params @param1", my_param)
```

Comment: Ok, and how do I have to write my sql query into the proc stock?

Comment: You can create the stored proc in your SQL database however you normally create them: `create procedure my_stored_proc as begin Select a,b from MyTableA inner join MyTableB on  MyTableA.column = MyTableB.column end`